# How to point Maven IDEA plugin what type of module to generate?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I have a project that consists of several modules (app. 10-12). I use maven idea plugin to generate `.iml` for each module, but I have one problem. All modules are of `JAVA_MODULE` type, but plugin generates main module as `J2EE_WEB_MODULE`. I think it is because there's .war files and `WEB_INF` folders in target folder, but these ones are for Tomcat usage. Anyway, at the end I must edit `.iml` file and change `J2EE_WEB_MODULE` to `JAVA_MODULE`.

Is there any way to make maven plugin generate a module of specific type? Or maybe there's a workaround that lets one change with maven, using regexp, module type in `.iml`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the [`maven-idea-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/), it is obsolete and has not been updated since 2008.

Just open the project by pointing to the `pom.xml`.

The guys at JetBrains has done a perfect job with their own maven integration.

Comment: I tried to create IDEA project based on maven pom.xml files - it generates correct project structure, but at the end I had to correct classpath because it is impossible to build project in IDEA then.

Comment: @Dragon What do you mean by *it is impossible to build project in IDEA then*? What is the problem?

Comment: When I make rebuild project, almost all the project is built, but at the end there're a lot of imports which are broken. So I need to change classpath and so on. Maybe I create IDEA project from Maven incorrectly, I'm still investigating it :)

Comment: Run `mvn clean idea:clean` to remove all generated files. Then start from fresh and open the top `pom.xml` from within IntelliJ. Make sure that the `.idea` folder is removed too (unless you still work with the old `.ipr` files).

Comment: Yes, I did as you said and still have almost 170 errors. There're some dependent modules, but maven build button is inactive. Anyway, thanks, I'll stick to this method :)